# Possible to switch Fn-status of only F2 and F11 function keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, function-keys

On an HP Spectre x360, the F-keys are by default in the "Fn"-state, where they do fairly handy things like turn up/down volume or brightness. But F11-for-fullscreen and F2-for-renaming are really handy – is it possible to switch Fn-state for *only* certain keys? (I know I can switch for all keys in BIOS, but I'd like to keep the best of both states …).

(I'm using XFCE/Xubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the cog wheel in the upper right hand corner of your screen and select "System Settings"

Select "Keyboard"

Go to the "Shortcuts" tab

Select "Windows" in the left panel

Find "Toggle Full Screen Mode"

When you do this it will wait for you to push your short cut ex.. Ctrl+F11 keys or just simply push the F11 key

To cancel push the Backspace key.

Taken from the url below

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Xubuntu – does this toggle fullscreen in e.g. Firefox when done under Unity?

Comment: Method 3: Keyboard shortcuts (which can be edited by going to the Settings Manager > Window Manager > Keyboard). One of them is for resizing windows with your keyboard. There is currently no keyboard shortcut set by default, but you can set one in the Window Manager dialog.

As soon as your keyboard-shortcut (in Xfce upstream its Alt+F8) is hit, you can then resize the window by either moving your mouse (no need to click or drag) or use your keyboard arrow keys.  Taken from the link https://xubuntu.org/news/window-resizing-in-xubuntu-and-xfce/ @unhammer

Comment: fullscreen is different from maximizing. And if I wanted to use several keypresses, I might as well hit `Alt-V F` in Firefox.